Persistent MalformedInputException After Java Update in Jenkins - Windows Setup
I'm facing a MalformedInputException: Input length = 4 error after updating both my Jenkins master and agent nodes to Java 21 on Windows. This only happens in production; our staging environment, running an identical pipeline, works fine with Java 21.
Current Setup:

OS: Windows on both master and agent nodes.
Java Version: Recently updated to Java 21.
Error: MalformedInputException: Input length = 4, triggered during a specific stage of the build.
Agent Version: Running the latest agent.jar.

Troubleshooting So Far:

Ensured agent.jar on both nodes is using Java 21.

Followed Snyk’s solution to set encoding, but no luck. Added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to the environmental parameters in Windows, both on master and agents.

Restarted services.


Additional Questions:

Are there any known compatibility issues with Java 21 and Jenkins on Windows?
Could there be specific encoding configurations in agent.jar or Jenkins that need adjusting after the update?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help.
[re20-server-tag-release] $ cmd.exe /C " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe" /make /outdir C:\jenkins-agent\workspace\re20-server-tag-release /d UsarQueSocket=1:ConUpTime=1:AntiExternos=0:Lac=1:DEBUGGING=0:PYMMO=1:UNLOCK_CPU=1 /out C:\jenkins-agent\workspace\re20-server-tag-release\vb6build12712032603954651177.log C:\jenkins-agent\workspace\re20-server-tag-release\Server.VBP " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
FATAL: Input length = 4
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to ao20-produccion
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1923)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:384)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1112)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1228)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1217)
        at hudson.FilePath.readToString(FilePath.java:2482)
        at PluginClassLoader for visual-basic-6//org.jenkinsci.plugins.vb6.VB6Builder.perform(VB6Builder.java:119)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:527)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1831)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:445)
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 4
    at java.base/java.lang.String.throwMalformed(String.java:1279)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.decodeUTF8_UTF16(String.java:1205)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.newStringUTF8NoRepl(String.java:759)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.newStringNoRepl1(String.java:790)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.newStringNoRepl(String.java:772)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.newStringNoRepl(System.java:2480)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readString(Files.java:3349)
    at Jenkins v2.479.1//hudson.FilePath$ReadToString.invoke(FilePath.java:2490)
    at Jenkins v2.479.1//hudson.FilePath$ReadToString.invoke(FilePath.java:2485)
    at Jenkins v2.479.1//hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3614)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:225)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:391)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:140)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Sending notification to Discord.
Finished: FAILURE

